# nodejs mysql parameter query failing

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using promise-mysql which is nodejs-mysql with Async/await. It usually works great, but I have one query that fails and I can't figure out why. Here is the code:

`INSERT INTO customers (name, phone, email, city, address, date_registered) VALUES ?`

```
await pool.query(sql, [customer]);
```

the parameter customer is this:

```
['string',NULL,'string',NULL,NULL,'2019-01-16 18:53:43']
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error message is the query producing?

Comment: Sorry, should have said that the error says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'string', NULL, 'string'"

Comment: Sounds like it's binding the array as a string rather than a list of values. So try putting parentheses around the binding: `INSERT INTO customers (name, phone, email, city, address, date_registered) VALUES (?)` Although it's probably better to bind each value separately, but this might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove square brackets from customer parameter like this:

```
await pool.query(sql, customer);
```

Since customer is already an array of parameters, you are passing an array of array as second argument. Hence it might be throwing error.